Show sender of WhatsApp conversation converted into SMS
I come from here: Send a SMS for every Android notification (goal: get notifications on Garmin Edge 1000)
I have a Forerunner 30 that I only receive SMS notifications on. I have managed to convert a WhatsApp notification into an SMS and am able to read its content, but I am not able to show the sender, I only see my own phone number. Does anyone have any ideas?



I don't know what I was thinking, I had the solution in front of me, I just needed to add a space between variables

Looks like you found the solution by yourself, which is great! But I think it can be improved a little bit more to directly answer the question, which parameter is the sender? You can [edit] your answer to add this information :)

I would suggest that Whatsapp is being secretive about it (for security reasons).  It sounds like a programming question to me.  Asking Tasker support may be the way to go.
